# Styling Django Model forms

Tags: css, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I was just wondering how do you style django model forms? I already made the css file but I don't know how to put classes in Model Form tags.'

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass this to the `attrs` of the widget:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        widgets = {
            'field_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
        }
```

or you can do this in the `__init__` method of the `ModelForm`:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs.update(class='myclass')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

Comment: That would help! Thanks sir :)